# R: Apply function to nested lists

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply, haversine

I have nested lists with numeric vales. In my case they are longitudes and latitudes sorted like this:

```
list1 <- list(1:50, 1:25, 1:30)
list2 <- list(1:50, 1:25)
list3 <- list(1:30)
list4 <- list(1:50, 1:25, 1:30, 1:45)
nested_lons1 <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4) 
nested_lons2 <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4) 
nested_lats1 <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4) 
nested_lats2 <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4)
```

Random numbers just for illustration purposes.
I would like to calculate the distance between two points of each nested list (list1 until list4) using the Haversine formula. I read that it is better to avoid for loops which is why I'm looking at lapply.

```
dist <- lapply(1:4, function(x) distHaversine(c(nested_lons1[x],nested_lats1[x]),
                                              c(nested_lons2[x],nested_lats2[x]), r = 6371))
```

This gives an error like "can't be converted to double". I think the index is also wrong, since the function should iterate through the first list's nested lists, then go to the nested lists in the second list and so on until the 4th one. How can I do this? Any other (better) approach? Thank you!

Comment: From `distHaversine` documentation: "longitude/latitude of point(s). Can be a vector of two numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude, second is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object"  While `nested_lons1[x]`, `nested_lats1[x]` are lists of lists.  Note that for example: `nested_lons1[[1]][[1]]` is the actual vector, `1:50`

Comment: @SteveM Do you mean that for lists of lists I have to use the actual vector like [[x]] [[x]] ?

Comment: I haven't played with the function.  Do an `str` on `nested_lons[1]`, `nested_lons[[1]]`, `nested_lons[[1]][1]`, `nested_lons[[1]][[1]]]` to compare how lists of lists are maintained..  Suggest you experiment with a single `distHaversine` function calculation outside of `lapply` to see which list call may work.

Comment: @SteveM It seems that nested_lons[[1]][[1]][1] works! It's the only one that accesses the right elements from the nested lists. But how can I redefine it as a loop? Do I need three indices in lapply? If so, how can I write the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list structures match, as they do in your example, it may be simpler to `unlist` and then `relist` the data. First `unlist` the lon/lat data and `cbind` to make 2-column matrices:

```
library(geosphere)
p1 <- cbind(unlist(nested_lons1), unlist(nested_lats1))
p2 <- cbind(unlist(nested_lons2), unlist(nested_lats2))
```

Now compute the distances and convert back to a list of the same structure:

```
d12 <- distHaversine(p1, p2)
d12.lst <- relist(d12, nested_lons1)
str(d12.lst)
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : num [1:50] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:25] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:50] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:25] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : num [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ :List of 4
#   ..$ : num [1:50] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:25] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#   ..$ : num [1:45] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Of course, this only works if the four nested lists have the same structure.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your approach but from d12 <- distHaversine(cbind(lons1, lats1), cbind(lons2, lats2)) I get an error: the list object can't be converted to 'double'?

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected the code. I accidentally included a line from an earlier attempt. It works now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It's working as expected even with more nested lists. I have only one more question regarding this line: d12.lst <- relist(d12, nested_lons1) How come that I don't have to do this for nested_lons2, nested_lats1 and nested_lats2 as well? Does it mean that "relist" just takes the structure from nested_lons1?

Comment: Yes. All of the lists must have the same structure so any one of them would work. The function is just copying the structure of the list, not the data.